# Nginx - where is error page file?

Tags: php, nginx

When I stop php5-fpm there appears error

```
"The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable." on site.
```

My question is, where is this "text"?

I need to change it.

Comment: You do not want to change the text as it is stored in the error pages bundled with your http server. Instead you want to _override_ the error page selected in case of an error to point to a custom error page you define.

Comment: `grep -Rn --color "The page you are looking for is tem" /` would probably give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an nginx error page. Look in the `/usr/share/nginx/` directory on your server.

Or `/usr/share/nginx/html/`